# C# - How to access member variable from reference to "object" class that refer to some other object type

Tags: c#, oop

I have a reference to class object that pointed to some class, say, XYZ as follow:

```
public class XYZ
{
     int x;
     int y;
     int z;
    XYZ()
    {
      x=0;
      y=1;
      z=2;
    }
};


object ObjRef;
ObjRef = new XYZ();
```

Now, I want to access member variable **x**, **y** and **z** through **ObjRef**. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

The class XYZ is inside client's DLL. I have loaded this class using

```
Assembly MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyName)

Type XYZType = MyAssembly.GetType("XYZ");
Object ObjectRef = Activator.CreateInstance(XYZType);
```

So i don't have direct access to XYZ. I have Object reference that pointed to XYZ.

Comment: I believe you'd have to cast `ObjRef` to `XYZ` to access the members.

Comment: I'm a little confused - if you've loaded the class, why can you not instantiate the class, even if it's from a third party DLL?

Comment: Tim, because the project that contains `Assembly.LoadFrom` has no reference to the client DLL. Any types defined in it will not be available at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes using private variables. You should use the reflection to access private property as well private variables when you must create instance via outside assembly which you cannot access directly.

You can use reflector with `BindingFlags.NonPublic` and `BindingFlags.Instance` flags

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(XYZ).GetFields(
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                         BindingFlags.Instance);
```

And access into private member following code statement below:

```
object objRef = new XYZ();
int x = (int)fields.Single(f => f.Name.Equals("x")).GetValue(objRef);
```

Answer (score 4):

Either use casting like other people have mentioned or if you don't know what to cast to at runtime, then use the [System.Type.GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield.aspx) method and use [BindingFlags.NonPublic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

By casting it from `object` back to `XYZ`:

```
XYZ a = (XYZ) ObjRef;
int result = a.x;
```

That will cause an exception if `ObjRef` isn't an `XYZ`.  You can also say:

```
XYZ a = ObjRef as XYZ;
```

which will return `null` if `ObjRef` isn't an `XYZ`.

Comment: I can't do that. class XYZ is in client's dll. I have load this dll using Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyName). so i have only objec reference to this instance. So i cant type cast by using (XYZ)

Comment: @someone_smiley: You really need to explain that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

For reading the x-value:
`((XYZ)ObjRef).x`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to the original type, but you do happen to know both the names AND the types of the fields that you want to access, then you can use reflection as the following program demonstrates:

(Note: This assumes that the field is private as per your original post. If it is public, change `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to `BindingFlags.Public`)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        void Run()
        {
            object obj = new XYZ();

            var xField = obj.GetType().GetField("x", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            int xValue = (int) xField.GetValue(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(xValue); // Prints 0

            xField.SetValue(obj, 42);  // Set private field value to 42
            xValue = (int)xField.GetValue(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(xValue); // Prints 42
        }
    }

    public class XYZ
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

        public XYZ()
        {
            x=0;
            y=1;
            z=2;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add public keyword to variable declaration. So it will be like this:

```
public int x;
```

Comment: public fields make hulk angry

Comment: I can't do that. class XYZ is in client's dll. I have load this dll using Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyName). so i have only objec reference to this instance

Comment: So `object` has a public variable named 'x'?

Comment: No. class XYZ has public x

Comment: You misunderstood my comment (or I misunderstood what you're trying to do).  `ObjRef` is of type `System.Object`.  I'm pretty sure that there is not a public `x` member in `System.Object`.

Comment: @Tim pls see update o my question. I will edit again if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @someone_smiley - Sorry...past my bedtime.  I thought Garath made your comment, not you.  My comment was directed to Garath's answer - I don't think it matters if XYZ has a public field declared, you still can't access it through ObjRef because ObjRef is of type Object.

Comment: @someone_smiley so the only way is to use reflection

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use public properties to access those variables instead of making it public. Although it may look quite overkill in some case, this is, I think, a best practice. I also think in most recent versions of .NET framework (I'm still using 2.0...) it ca be performed quite simply with less code as soon as you have simple getter and setter.

I think [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) can help

Comment: Automatically implemented properties are part of the *language*, not part of the framework - so you can use them when targeting .NET 2, so long as you're using a C# 3+ compiler. But I don't believe the question was really about that anyway...

Comment: Yeah now with the update of the question I realize my answer doesn't help at all. Thanks for the info about automatically implemented properties though, I will look back into it !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should really do is that you should define an interface in a separate DLL that is then referenced by your code as well as the client DLL. Class XYZ should implement that interface and you should utilize that interface to access X, Y & Z, as follows:

```
// this is in the DLL defining the interface
public interface IXyz
{
    int X { get; }

    int Y { get; }

    int Z { get; }
}

// this would be in the client DLL that you dynamically load in your code
public class Xyz : IXyz
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }

    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```

And then finally,

```
// this is your code where you create XYZ
IXyz xyz = new Xyz();

int x = xyz.X;
```

Comment: This is of course assuming if you have any control over the client DLL. If you do not, I suppose you could always create a wrapper class and enclose the reflection logic in there.